# Rails 4, redirect to "pages/congrats"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, redirect

I have a problem after registration a new user. I need to redirect user to page with congrats that he was registered. Adress is: /pages/bravo . But redirect does'nt work.

```
    def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to "pages/bravo"
  else
    render "new"
end
end
```

It will returns the same page of registration without a redirecting.
Thank you.

Comment: If its returning to the same page then your record might not be getting saved in database. Use `@user.save!` instead of `@user.save` and see if you get any exception while registering a new user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming bravo is an action in the controller

```
redirect_to :controller => 'pages', :action => 'bravo'
```

Comment: Oh, thank. I thought that it may be something like that))) But I'll use the newest form: 
redirect_to controller: 'pages', action: 'bravo'

Comment: you could also do `bravo_pages_path`

Answer (score 1):

```
if @user.save!
    redirect_to bravo_pages_path , notice: "Success"
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "Error"
    render "new" 
end
```